# Library of ISO standards

Tags: c#, standards, iso

Is there any library that covers ISO standards of international abbreviations, formats and other, or everybody uses his version of CountryCodes like:

```
    public enum CountryCode
    {
        AL, // Albania
        AD, // Andorra
        AM, // Armenia
        AT, // Austria
        ...
    }
```

Want to have [country codes](http://www.iso.org/iso/english_country_names_and_code_elements), [currency and funds name and code elements](http://www.iso.org/iso/support/faqs/faqs_widely_used_standards/widely_used_standards_other/currency_codes/currency_codes_list-1.htm)

BCL implements many ISO standards but they spread among a lot of classes. Will be useful when you know, that if you need to format date by ISO 8601, you use Iso.Formatting.Format(DateTime.Now);

PS:
I know about `System.Globalization.CultureInfo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RegionInfo class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.aspx) is your primary resource.  It includes currency names (ISO, English and native) and two and three letter region names.

Comment: It pretty close. I knew about it, but it is not very useful (for ex. it is hard to find country by Currency code). I thought about something more generic.

Comment: It's got the data you need.  Treat it like a data source, write your own code to make it useful in your program.

Comment: I mark this as answer, because it looks like right answer. But it is my fault that I composed not definite question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want ISO standards, a good place to start is iso.org:

http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue.htm

Comment: Good place, but I didn't find (and sure that will not find) there something like .Net assembly or c# code snippet.